# Workflow for working on a Perl6 library

Tags: raku

I am trying to get into Perl6 by working on a module but I can't seem to figure out what the right workflow is.

Right now I am using [rakudobrew](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/) and I want to add SSL/TLS support to [HTTP::Client](https://github.com/supernovus/perl6-http-client).

Where does rakudobrew store libraries? What do I do to use the modified version?

Thank you for your time and patience helping me get started with Perl6.

Comment: Just use git to clone HTTP::Client, hack on it, then submit a pull request.

Comment: *What do I do to use the modified version?* During development, plain old `perl6 -Ilib ...` from within the repository's root directory should do the trick

Comment: A handy command is`panda info HTTP::Client`, which gives you various details. At the moment everything is in git, so you can do a git clone of the source-url.

Answer (score 1):

Christoph is right; `perl6 -Ilib` or `perl -I./lib` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't need to care about where the libraries are stored. If you use rakudobrew or some other method, `zef install .` will put the libraries where they can be reached. So as answered above, just hack away at your version of the library after cloning it, then test locally with `zef test .` and install it globally with `zef install .`